# Does assembly code include the labels, or are labels just syntax decoration?

Tags: assembly

Are labels that  are usually put before x86 instructions, such as

```
0x09: mov eax, 1001
```

(a line I made up) a part of the assembly code?

On the one hand, I feel that assembly instructions such as   jmp would make no sense without labels; on the other hand, online assembling sites such as https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm, does not seem to  recognise labels as a part of the assembly code. Reason why I have this question.

[edit] By assembly code, I mean the lowest-level human readable code that is closest to 0-1 machine code. By assemble, or assembling, I mean the process of translating assembly code into 0-1 machine code.

By labels, I actually meant for the addresses.

Comment: Where did you get this line from?  Disassemblers often put an address in front of each instruction to make it easier to cross reference the program with the disassembly.

Comment: There isn't really a precise definition of what constitutes "an assembler", nor what exactly is "assembly code".  Certainly one would strongly desire labels if writing a program of any size, but for an "assembler" that is just meant for a couple of instructions at a time, maybe it's not so necessary.  You can still assemble jmp instructions by hardcoding the addresses or displacements.

Comment: Oh, based on your example, you don't mean *labels* (which are human-readable alphanumeric strings and `0x09` would usually not be legal), but rather *instruction addresses*.  Whether a disassembler chooses to provide those might be a convenience feature, but a useful one.  You would not use them in the *input* to an assembler.

Comment: Assembly includes labels, binary executables sometimes have labels as annotations, but the machine code the processor sees never has labels.  However, your example is *dis*-assembly, not assembly.

Comment: The addresses of each instruction is its position within the `.text` section (or wherever it is).  CPUs don't need named labels, they just index memory like an array.  Relative or absolute addressing just works without having to search for a matching label or address, the CPU just computes the address and fetches code from there.  Just like `x = array[i]` works without "labels" in the array, just values, for fetching data instead of code.

Comment: By labels I meant for addresses. Maybe too late to change the question.

Comment: It's not too late; comments are intended to help improve posts (questions or answers).  There is an existing answer which assumes you meant actual asm labels as in `foo:`  and `dec ecx` / `jnz foo`, but it's a pretty short answer and I suspect is answering a question that already has other duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between assembly language and machine code, but the two are often used interchangeably. Assembly language is what you're writing in your text editor. Machine code is what gets run by the machine itself. The assembly language source code is *assembled* into machine language, much like C code is compiled into machine code.

Labels are just for your convenience, they get automatically converted into memory addresses by the assembler. Otherwise, every time you write more code you'd have to adjust all of your jumps!

Comment: By machine code, do you mean sequence of 0-1?

Comment: Yes, but the disassembler usually displays it to you in hexadecimal because that's easier to read. The CPU encodes every instruction as one or more bytes, the assembler converts your assembly program into those bytes.

Comment: You said "much like C code is compiled into machine code."  Is C compiled to 0-1 sequence directly or to assembly code first? Out of curiority.

Comment: C usually becomes assembly first. Eventually everything needs to become machine code, since it's the only thing the computer can actually run.

Answer (score 1):

The labels and other non-instructions are very much part of the language and they are the primary places that makes assembly languages incompatible for the same target.   How comments are defined, how labels are defined rules for labels, other directives.  Macro syntax, etc.  All part of the language.  If it were not then the assembler would not fail to parse/assemble the code.

It is like asking if function names or function prototypes, typedefs, defines, etc are part of the C language.

Comment: where it gets tricky is for a particular assembly language (which is defined by the tool, not target) is can you not use labels, and if so what is the syntax for that.   jmp loop_top is one thing but, for each assembly language, how do you define, jump backward 8 bytes.   I would expect to find some that do not support non-label offsets and some without the value of the destination address being supported.